# SED command to change the header

Tags: r, unix, sed, awk

Well, I have about 114 files that I want to join side-by-side based on the 1st column that each file shares, which's the ID number. Each file consists of 2 columns and over 400000 lines. I used `write.table` to join those tables together in one table and I got X's in my header. For example, my header should be like:

> ID 1_sample1 2_sample2 3_sample3

But I get it like this:

> ID X1_sample1 X2_sample2 X3_sample3

I read about this problem and found out the `check.names` get rid of this problem, but in my case when I use `check.names` I get the following error:

> "unused argument (check.name = F)"

Thus, I decided to use sed to fix the problem, it actually works great, BUT it joins the 2nd line and the 1st line. For instance, my 1st column and second column should be something like this:

> ID 1_sample1 2_sample2 3_sample
>
> cg123 .0235 2.156 -5.546

But I get the following instead:

> ID 1_sample1 2_sample2 3_sample cg123 .0235 2.156 -5.546

Can any one check this code for me, please. I might've done something wrong to not get each line separated from the other.

```
head -n 1 inFILE | tr "\t" "\n" | sed -e 's/^X//g' | sed -e 's/\./-/' | sed -e 's/\./(/' |sed -e 's/\./)/' | tr "\n" "\t" > outFILE
tail -n +2 beta.norm.txt >> outFILE
```

Comment: Try improving your spelling and your formatting, making sure we can understand what you mean. Also, some sample input and desired output will be helpful.

Comment: Improved formatting will help, but surely there is a way to accomplish what you're looking for in R proper. Can you share a bit of the actual data (paste the result of `dput(head(yourdata))`).

Comment: Text processing of multiple fields is usually most easily done using `awk`. Show a "input line" and "desired output line", explaining what differences you want to achieve, and you will get some good answers.

Comment: Do you have column with exactly the same names in both of your tables? If youdo, it might be the function merge() that creates those x's in your column names. Those x's are added in order to make the column names unique. You can control this in merge with the argument suffixes.

Comment: @Floris I already update my post. Hopefully it's more understandable now

Comment: No I have no duplicates in name each column has it's unique identifier. And I used `write.table` not `merge()` @JTT

Comment: OK, those X's are generated, because your column names can't start with a number. Maybe just remove the 1_, etc. from the beginning of each column name by hand? In R, something like `colnames(tab)<-c("ID", "Sample1", "Sample2", "Sample3")`. "tab" there is the name of your data frame in R.

Comment: I am deleting my answer..I would tell if I could do that

Answer (score 2):

If your data is tab delimited, the simple fix would be

```
sed '1,1s/\tX/\t/g' < inputfile > outputfile

1,1     only operate on the range "line 1 to line 1"
\tX     find tab followed by X
/\t/    replace with tab
g       all occurrences
```

It does seem as though your original attempt does more than just strip the X - it also changes successive dots to `(-)` but you don't show in your example why you need that. The reason your code joins the first two lines is that you only replace `\n` with `\t` in your last `tr` command - which leaves you with no `\n` at the end of the line.

You need to attach a `\n` at the end of your first line before concatenating lines 2 and beyond with your second command.  Experiment with

```
head -n 1 inFILE | tr "\t" "\n" | sed -e 's/^X//g' | sed -e 's/\./-/' | sed -e 's/\./(/' |sed -e 's/\./)/' | tr "\n" "\t" > outFILE
echo "\n" >> outFile
tail -n +2 beta.norm.txt >> outFILE
```

whether that works depends on your OS. There are other ways to add a newline...

**edit** using `awk` is probably much cleaner - for example

```
awk '(NR==1){gsub(" X"," ", $0);}{print;}' inputFile > outputFile
```

Explanation:

```
(NR==1)                for the first line only (record number == 1) do:
{gsub(" X","", $0);}   do a global substitution of "space followed by X", with "space"

                       for all lines (including the one that was just modified) do:
{print;}'              print the whole line
```

Comment: I am deleting my answer..I would tell if I could do that

Comment: Hi @Floris I already used the `awk` command but it didn't get rid of the X at the beginning at all. I tried ur fix for see but it also did not work. Generated a file with only `\n` in it